# Linear Regression line not showing in plot

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pandas, linear-regression, matplotlib

It's a silly problem, I know, but it's getting my nerves. Everything seems fine, but I cannot get the line to show on the plot.

I've put it in a public Google [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1s0m3Kh9q8Z448-Avq3_KndgMfq4YkhUe#scrollTo=jS_krrhzqgoB), for your convenience.

**t** represents months, and **f_t** are sales (accumulated). I feed the model 12 months of data, and use the 13th month for prediction. Simple.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

muestra = []
# creamos las 13 muestras de acuerdo a la fórmula provista en la Situación Problemática.
for i in range(1,14):
  t = 3*i + 2*(random.uniform(-1, 1))
  muestra.append((i, t))


df = pd.DataFrame(muestra)
df.rename(columns={0:"t", 1:"f_t"}, inplace=True)

train = df.loc[:11]
test = df.loc[12:]

X_train = train.t.values.reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = train.f_t.values

X_test = test.t.values.reshape(-1, 1)
y_test = test.f_t.values

LR_model = LinearRegression()
LR_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = LR_model.predict(X_test)

%matplotlib inline

plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, label="Regresión Lineal", color='g')
plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, label="Muestra",color='b') 
plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, label="Mes 13",color='r')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Meses (t)')
plt.ylabel('Ventas (f(t))')
plt.title("Análisis en base a la técnica de regresión lineal simple")
plt.show()
```

Now, I get the scatter points, but not the regression line. What am I missing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to plot a single predicted point, When I believe you are actually looking to plot the fitted model. To do that you'll need the coef_ and intercept_ properties of the model. I have included a link to the documentation on this if you want to learn more.

```
%matplotlib inline
f_x = lambda x: (x * LR_model.coef_) + LR_model.intercept_
x_range = [0,13]
LR_model_y = list(map(f_x, x_range))
plt.plot(x_range,LR_model_y, label="Regresión Lineal", color='g')
```

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html

Comment: Great! That solved it. Thank you so much, Levon.